# I am trying to force an input value of type number in react to take only positive integers

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I have this input tag of type number and right now, it takes both negative and positive value. I want the input field to only accept only positive natural numbers

```
I have tried 
<input type="number" min="0">
```

and for some reason, it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min` property:

```
<input type='number' min={1} step={1} />
```

Answer (score 0):

This might works for you.

```
 <input type="number" name="test_name" min="0" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');">
```

But if you are working with forms in react, I would recommend using Formik and Yup(validation).

Formik: https://formik.org/docs/tutorial
Yup : https://github.com/jquense/yup

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` so don't need any library.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(1)

const onChange = (e) => {
  const reg = /^$|^[0-9]+$/;
  const newValue = e.target.value;
  if (reg.test(newValue)) {
   setValue(newValue);
  }
}

<input value={state} onChange={onChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out this also works well.

```
   handleChange=(e)=>{
   this.setState({
   value: e.target.value
   })
```

```
   <input type="number" 
   value={this.state.value}
   onChange={e=> e.target.value > 0 && handleChange}
 />
```

this is the magic here:
`e.target.value > 0`
it will force the input not to take a negative value.